# Valence electron energy and scattering angles in Compton scattering

Tags: special-relativity, photons, atomic-physics, scattering

The [Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering#See_also) of the X-ray from electron is depicted below with x-axis being  the dir. of the incident photon:
[image]
Its wavelength shift amounts to:
$$ \lambda_f - \lambda_i = \frac{h}{m_ec}(1-cos\theta) \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$
where $m_e$ is the electron rest mass and $\frac{h}{m_ec}$ is known as the Compton wavelength of the electron. Equation\ref{eq1} can be derived from the conservation of momentum:
$$\begin{align}
p_i &= p_f cos\theta+p_e cos\varphi \ \ \ (x-component) \tag{2}\label{eq2}\\
0 &= p_f sin\theta - p_e sin\varphi \ \ \ (y-component)\tag{3}\label{eq3}
\end{align}$$
and the conservation of energy:
$$
p_i c + m_e c^2  = p_f c + \frac{m_e c^2}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{v}{c})^2}} \tag{4}\label{eq4}
$$
My first question is that $m_e c^2$ on the left of \ref{eq4} representing the energy of a valence electron orbiting in the outermost shell of an atom (Bohr's model) and yet we treat it as at rest ($v=0$). Is that a correct assumption?

With the help of the half angle identity for tangent:
$$ tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{1-cos\theta}{sin\theta} \tag{5}\label{eq5}
$$
we can express $\varphi$ in terms of $\theta$ by combining equations \ref{eq1}, \ref{eq2} and \ref{eq3} as
$$ cot\varphi = (1+\frac{h}{\lambda_i m_e c})tan\frac{\theta}{2} \tag{6}\label{eq6}
$$
My second question is that, given angle $\theta$,  equation \ref{eq6} can tell us angle $\varphi$. But do we know the probability of having a $\theta$ angle or is it purely random?

Comment: In Compton's model, there is no atom present.